# Simplify Product of Sums

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Similar question to:
[Boolean Algebra - Product of Sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299478/boolean-algebra-product-of-sums)

I was given a truth table and asked to give the sums-of-products and the product-of-sums expressions.

I reduced the sums-of-products expression to this, which I believe is correct:

$$F(x,y,z) = xy + yz + xz$$

I have so far reduced my product-of-sums expression to this:

$$F(x,y,z) = (x+y+z)(x+y+z’)(x+y’+z)(x’+y+z)$$

but I can't figure out how to further reduce my product-of-sums, whilst still retaining the "product-of-sums" form and not converting back to "sums-of-products" form. If someone could show me how to further reduce the product-of-sums, I would be appreciative if you could explain which Boolean identity is being used at each stage of of the simplification (i.e. Distributive Law, DeMorgan's Law etc). Thanks!

Comment: How about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: I preferably want to do this question without using K maps, as we haven't been taught them yet. I am expected to be able to achieve this without a K map I believe.

Comment: What I can think of is applying negation of negation and then de morgan in sop.

Comment: Ok, so I did that. Can you confirm that, for the same truth table, if the sum-of-products is: F(x,y,z) = xy + yz + xz, then the product-of-sums would be: F(x,y,z) = (x+y)(y+z)(x+z) ? Thanks so far

Comment: Seems like it. You can always verify by a truth table. or a program.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x+y+z)(x+y+z')=x+y$ etc.

Enter twice  the dummy term $(x+y+z)$  into $F(x,y,z)=(x+y+z)(x+y+z')(x+y'+z)(x'+y+z).$ Then $$F(x,y,z)=\underbrace{(x+y+z)(x+y+z')}\underbrace{\color{blue}{(x+y+z)}(x+y'+z)}\underbrace{\color{blue}{(x+y+z)}(x'+y+z)}$$ so $$F(x,y,z)=(x+y)(x+z)(y+z).$$